# How to find $δ$ given $\varepsilon = 1$ of $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$, $f(x)= 1/(x(x-2))$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been asked to find a $\delta$ given $\varepsilon=1$ for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x(x-2)}$, and I'm stuck right after setting up the $\vert f(x)-L\vert$ portion of the definition. I ended up with an inequality that looks like this:

$$-1<\frac{1}{x(x-2)}+1<1$$

Then I subtracted 1 from both sides and am left with with this

$$-2<\frac{1}{x(x-2)}<0$$

This is where I'm stuck.. I've been told that I can do a reciprocal if both sides of the inequality are positive, but since one side is negative I'm not certain if it would be the correct step. Apologies for formatting. first time poster.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last inequality:
$$-2 < \frac{1}{x(x-2)} < 0$$
Note that this is equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x(x-2)} &< 0 \\
\frac{1}{x(x-2)} &> -2
\end{align}\end{cases} \implies 
\begin{cases}
x \in (0,2) \\[1mm]
x \in \left(-\infty \:,\:0\right)\cup \left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2},\:\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\cup \left(2,\:\infty \:\right)\end{cases}$$
Now, find the intersecti0n of the two results:
$$x\in \left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2},\:\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: it shouldnt be now that         |x-1|<delta,      and |x-1|=|(0, sqrt(2)/2)|, so delta =sqrt(2)/2 ?

Comment: yes you are right @paweta